# Open a file in the default text editor programmatically

Tags: desktop, editors, mime-types

I'm writing a program and I need to implement opening a particular file in a text editor. The file type has a different association by default (it's associated to the program itself), so calling `xdg-open $file` wouldn't work. Using `$EDITOR` is sub-optimal because it usually contains the terminal text editor, and I'd like to open a GUI text editor if that's the first preference. It is also unclear how to find the default terminal emulator to open a terminal `$EDITOR`.

I can query the (possibly GUI) editor with `xdg-mime query default text/plain`, which gives me a `.desktop` file, but I'm not sure how to go about actually running it, especially since it may contain `Terminal=true` which then again raises an issue of figuring out what the default terminal is.

To clarify, the program is not a script or something which *already runs in the terminal*. It is a GUI application, so launching a terminal editor would require figuring out what the default terminal is.

So, what's the best way to programmatically open a file in a default, possibly GUI, text editor?

Comment: If a GUI text editor is the first preference of _the user_, they should set `EDITOR` accordingly, IMHO.  What if a user isn't even using X, i.e. they are using your script on a head-less machine without ever having used _any_ graphical environment with their account?

Comment: Then, if it is indeed a terminal editor, how do I open _that_? I'd need to somehow retrieve the default terminal emulator?

Comment: My point is that you, as the script writer, should not worry about what editor the user wants or can use. It would be enough to use `"$EDITOR" "$file"` (or possibly `"${EDITOR:-vi}" "$file"` to use a default value) in the script, and then document the fact that `$EDITOR` is use for editing files from within the script.  This is what most other utilities do. You would otherwise built in a dependency on a particular set of applications.  This is personal opinion on my part though.

Comment: The problem is that it's not a script, so I can't just call `$EDITOR` if it's a terminal editor. I'd need to launch an actual terminal.

Comment: This may need clarifying in the actual question.

Comment: Good point, I added a paragraph about that.

Comment: I was talking about it with our admins. If your app is a GUI app, it should try to use the default GUI editor and it's the user's responsibility to have a wrapper for their terminal editor in place if they so desire. The issue is there's no such thing as **POSIX defaults for GUI apps**. The only such thing exists within the boundary of a given Desktop Environment config, hence, the only sensible way of implementing that is to guess the DE, then check the DE-specific config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*.desktop` file you get by calling `xdg-mime query default text/plain` is in one of two locations:

```
$HOME/.local/share/applications/
/usr/share/applications/
```

So you need to look for it there, then parse the `Exec=` line and run it passing all the arguments, e.g.:

```
$(grep Exec /usr/share/applications/seahorse.desktop | cut -d= -f2) "$@"
```

To determine the default terminal emulator on debian-like distributions you can run the following and similarly parse the output to get the path:

```
update-alternatives --query x-terminal-emulator
```

or just try to run the command you need directly:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "your command here"
```

If you need to make it distribution agnostic you'll need to implement Desktop Environment guessing as it seems to depend on the way each DE stores its configuration. You might want to take a look at [xdg-terminal](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/tree/scripts/xdg-terminal.in) code which is part of xdg utilities package responsible for running the default terminal (but for some reason isn't distributed).

Comment: `update-alternatives` seems to not be present on my system (Arch Linux).

Comment: Good catch, it's for Debian derivatives. Try `x-terminal-emulator -e $your_command` but my guess is it's Debian as well... I'll update the answer when I find a more POSIX solution.

Comment: Yeah, `x-terminal-emulator` isn't present here either, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, the only "official" way of doing it I found is `xdg-terminal` but I can't find it installed on any of my distributions. You might need to duplicate what it does.